# Unir informacion de varias tablas en una sola llamada detalle

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito ayuda. Tengo tres tablas y estas quiero que se visualicen en una tabla llamada detalle_ingreso aplicando código php y mysql.  La tabla detalle tiene que tener su propio ID y traer las informacion de cada tabla y almacenarla en el detalle

Comment: Si a todo... ahora como queres que te ayuden? nadie lo va a escribi por vos...

Comment: Mi pregunta es si se podria realizar con una  consulta uniendo las tres tablas en el detalle

Comment: si, se puede...

Comment: Con INNER JOIN? se incrementaria el ID en la tabla detalle?

Comment: te recomandaria estudiar bien SQL.. lo que estas pidiendo no es complejo... y un join no incrementa ID... no entiendo tu pregunta...

Comment: Por eso mi interrogante, necesito enviar la informacion de las tres tablas a la de detalle y que esta me permita generar un ID para cada registro que va agregando en el detalle. Me podrias ayudar enviando algun tutorial porfavor?

Comment: El id deberia ser automatico, y no recomiendo tutoriales.. En este sitio no recomendamos nada...

Comment: Buenas, Luis, no está claro a qué te refieres con "consolidar". Si te refieres a que si puedes crear esa estructura de tablas relacionadas, como te indica gbianchi, sí, es posible. Con MySQL puedes crear esas tablas y con PHP puedes generar los insert y los select sobre ellas, teniendo en cuenta que si estableces esas relaciones mediante claves foráneas, eres tú el que tiene que cuidar que se cumplan cuando generes los insert.

Comment: @RubioRic Las relaciones ya las realice. Pero mi duda seria como podria generar el insert en esa tabla detalle que no sea un select, si no que a medida que se vayen agregando en las demas tablas, la tabla detalle se llene automaticamente con su ID y la informacion de las demas tablas

Comment: Ah mira.. ahora tenes otra pergunta, un poco mas enfocada y valida... la tabla del medio, es para ser llenada no cuando se llenan las de afuera, si no cuando ocurre la relacion entre las tres.... y no se llena automaticamente, salvo que necesites que sea automatico por algo... por que queres que sea automatico??

Comment: @gbianchi Si, necesito que la tabla detalle solo me permita visualizar la data de las demas tablas sin tener que tener un form y presionar un boton para almacenar en ella. Cada una de esas tablas envia la informacion y esta se visualiza en el detalle. Requiero que sea automatico por esa misma razon.

Comment: ahora lo que decis, no tiene nada de sentido... vos queres que esa tabla sea un conjunto de las otras tres.. o sea, si agrego una lista, queres que en la tabla central se guarden todas las combinaciones con esa nueva lista?

Comment: @gbianchi No, que la tabla detalle se pueda insertar sin necesidad de un formulario.

Comment: si que podrias, con un trigger..

Answer (score 0):

Se puede, pero tendrías que hacerlo de dos maneras.

- creando previamente una tabla temporal con un campo identity y dejarlo ahí el resultado.
- usando un procedimiento almacenado que te recorra las tablas y te entregue un resultado de la tabla tempora.

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]